# Unresolved constraint in bundlecom.jira.test.MyProject requirement osgi.wiring.package

Tags: java, spring, maven, jira, jira-plugin

I have a problem. I search on the internet and countn't really find right answear. It started in my project for JIRA plugin. Then I make new project and add 1 by 1 dependecys to check where the problem is. I get the following error.

```
>  ___ FAILED PLUGIN REPORT _____________________
> 
>  1 plugin failed to load during JIRA startup.
> 
>    
>        com.jira.test.MyProject' - 'MyProject'  failed to load.
>                Cannot start plugin: com.jira.test.MyProject
>                        Unresolved constraint in bundlecom.jira.test.MyProject [166]: Unable to resolve 166.0: missing
>
> requirement [166.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=bsh)
```

My POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jira.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <organization>
        <name>Example Company</name>
        <url>http://www.example.com/</url>
    </organization>

    <name>MyProject</name>
    <description>This is the com.jira.test:MyProject plugin for Atlassian JIRA.</description>
    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add dependency on jira-core if you want access to JIRA implementation classes as well as the sanctioned API. -->
        <!-- This is not normally recommended, but may be required eg when migrating a plugin originally developed against JIRA 4.x -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- WIRED TEST RUNNER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Uncomment to use TestKit in your project. Details at https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-testkit -->
        <!-- You can read more about TestKit at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Smarter+integration+testing+with+TestKit -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-testkit-client</artifactId>
            <version>${testkit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.context</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC01</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                    <!-- Uncomment to install TestKit backdoor in JIRA. -->
                    <!--
                    <pluginArtifacts>
                        <pluginArtifact>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jira-testkit-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${testkit.version}</version>
                        </pluginArtifact>
                    </pluginArtifacts>
                    -->
                    <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                    <enableFastdev>false</enableFastdev>

                    <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                    <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                    <instructions>
                        <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>

                        <!-- Add package to export here -->
                        <Export-Package>
                            com.jira.test.api,
                        </Export-Package>

                        <!-- Add package import here -->
                        <Import-Package>
                            <!--org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional" org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional", *-->
                            org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:=*, org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:=*, *
                        </Import-Package>

                        <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered -->
                        <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>atlassian-spring-scanner</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- process-classes seems to be skipped if you are using scala
                             so perhaps use prepare-package -->
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Enable this to get build-time logging of annotations atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin has noticed -->
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <jira.version>7.2.2</jira.version>
        <amps.version>6.2.11</amps.version>
        <plugin.testrunner.version>1.2.3</plugin.testrunner.version>
        <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.13</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
        <!-- This key is used to keep the consistency between the key in atlassian-plugin.xml and the key to generate bundle. -->
        <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</atlassian.plugin.key>
        <!-- TestKit version 6.x for JIRA 6.x -->
        <testkit.version>6.3.11</testkit.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

my java :

```
package com.jira.test;


import com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.export.ExportAsService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.inject.Named;

@ExportAsService
@Component
@Named("IssueCreatedResolvedListener")
public class IssueCreatedResolvedListener {


}
```

Ass soon as I add `@Component` and its dependency (`org.springframework`), faild to load plugin. Can anyone tell me how could I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well find answer by myself finally. Looked into dependency documentation and I change version and add scope provided.

In case anyone else will have the same issue as me, here is what you need to do: change dependency with this one. It fixed problem for me.

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```